# Execute load test on TestSuite in SoapUI

Tags: soapui, testcase, test-suite

I am using soapUI 4.6.4 version and had some test cases written which i clubbed into a TestSuite. Now i wanted to run **loadtest on TestSuite** itself i.e all the test cases under **Testsuite** should be executed repetatively. I can see the loadtest option on testcase

[image: LoadTest option on testcase]

But i can't see any load test option on testsuite iteslf

[image: No loadtest option available]

Please suggest me how to run loadtest on testsuite Itself
(Note : TestSuite names have been blurred out)

Comment: Is it that you need to run the test suite for specified number of times? If so, then you may not be really looking at load test then. Please clarify.

Comment: @Anand j. Kadhi why dont you create load test for each of your test case in test suite and run only those steps through groovy ? would that work for you?